# Installing SSL Certificate in PHP Xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, windows-server-2008-r2

How to Enable and Install SSL Certificate in XAMPP on windows server 2008?
How to make my website **https** enable?

Comment: Did you ask google first ?

Comment: a few seconds of googling:

https://www.adam.co.za/setup-https-in-xampp/

Comment: no please give me detail for that step by step

Comment: Click the link, dude.

Answer (score 0):

Here the few steps to create and install a SSL certificate on your xampp windows server

1 Create a Private Key
Command : openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
2 Generate Certificate signing Request
Command: openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
3 Sign the Certificate
command : openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
4.Install and Configure the Certificate
copy server.key and server.crt to crypt directory and configure the ssl conf for your web app
5. Restart the Apache server.

Reference
[Read more here](http://www.opencodez.com/apache/ssl-certificate-and-install-in-xampp.htm)